# Schedule for planning program

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm about to create an ASP.net MVC3 application where I need to make a schedule.

The Schedule has to contain all workers in  the company on y-axis, and for each worker there should be days/week/month on the x-axis.

Something like this:

http://www.daypilot.org/scheduler.html

except instead of rooms there should be workers names.

Now comes the tricky part, when admin go in to the system and click on any day for a worker, the color of that specific day has to change, to for example red.

The problem I have right now is, I cant figure out which way will be smartest to do this?

Should I make it with a GridView, or find an external free control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer without knowing all your requirements, but it sounds like just a regular html table with jQuery for adding `onclick` behavior and some CSS should suffice.

Take a look at the [MvcContrib Grid](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid) which lets you easily add tables or extend it to deal with custom data. [Here's](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2009/02/08/rewriting-the-mvccontrib-grid/) an overview of it.

As for changing the color of a specific day, if you define each day with its own css class you can target all cells with that class to change the background color. Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".day1").click("toggleBackground('day1')");
});

function toggleBackground(name) {
    $("." + name).css("background", "red");
}
```

Note: not tested. Also, this is a very rough idea but gives you one possible way of doing it.

Comment: well i can try, but i need to figure out a way how to will it in the right way. Colors is a realy problem, because browser wont remember them anyway after restart. Maybe u know any control i can buy for this?

Comment: if you need changes to be saved even if the user restarts their browser, now you're looking at saving data externally - most likely to a database. There is no control that you can create or buy that will save data if the user restarts their browser.